# accessing android widget controls

Tags: android, controls, widget

Probably a stupid question, but where and how do I access my widget controls?
With normal programs I call `setContentView(R.layout.blah)` and then use `findViewById(R.id.blah)`
to access the controls, but how do I do the same for widgets? Do I need to call `setContentView()` somewhere or..? The widget looks just fine without calling it anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean "widgets" as in the widgets on the device's home screen, or do you mean widgets as in specialized View sub classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it comes out there's now way to access them directly. Instead you have to do this:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = 
        new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.folder_view_mywidget);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(ctx, FolderViewProvider.class);
```

Then you use methods from `Remoteviews` to set all the fields you want like this:

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text1_1, "text");
```

And then finally you call this to execute the changes:

```
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```